# What is the default path setting for windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, path

I accidentally changed my path in control panel!

What should I set it to?

Comment: This is a good time to remember why we need backups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the "normal" path should be `%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\`

Comment: with a semicolon at the end? seriously? windows 8 has a semicolon at the end? can you check  that?

Comment: @barlop Apparently not - I just installed 8.1 in VMware and there isn't one. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: With a backslash at the end of the last path, when there are no backslashes at the end of the other paths?

Comment: @barlop It's there, unless VMware changes something, but I didn't use Easy Install or install VMware Tools